# MARIE: My Skipcond 400 doesn't seem to stop the program from barreling through the loop =C What is wrong here, I do not even know?

Tags: marie

```
    Input
    Store   b
    Output
    Input
    Store   c
    Output
Loop,   Load    a
    Add b
    Store   a
    Load    c
    Subt    i
    Store   c
    Output
    Skipcond 400
    Jump Loop
    Load    a
    Output

    Halt

a, DEC 0
b, DEC 0
c, DEC 0
i, DEC 1
z, DEC 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `subt` instruction shall subtract one (1) from `c`, wouldn't you need to use immediate addressing, like `#i`?